# display image after row click of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to have an image displayed from a row click of gridview. not part of gridview, so should be outside of gridview when have image. It will show different images based to a value from a column in the gridview. I have tried a couple of ways, such as using gridview on row data bound plus on selected index changed. But I just could not even have the image displayed upon row click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we assume that the GridView has a column with the path name to the image?

The markup can say be this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <div style="float:left">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="Image Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Image" HeaderText="Image Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:40px">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="302px" Width="448px" />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

data table:

[image]

Results:
[image]

I clicked on dog in the grid, and above was the result.

Edit: it would seem that the user wants a row click and NOT necessary a button on the page.

Ok, button has been removed.

Code is now this:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, ImageName, Image from tblImage",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Image1.ImageUrl = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text

End Sub
```

so we now add a click row event to the WHOLE row.

Note that you MUST add this to the first line in the page directive:

```
 EnableEventValidation="false"
```

The above goes in the VERY first line of the markup.

We now add two more events.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Image1.ImageUrl = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text

End Sub
```

So now the button can be REMOVED from the row - you can click anywhere on the row. And I suppose we could hide the 3rd column - the "url of the image"

Comment: I see. Am I able to not have a button inside gridview and just select a row by clicking on it, then display the picture? Because my boss don really want to have a button inside it.

Comment: See my NEW code and edit. I have added a row click to the gridview. You can thus now remove the button - the code works with JUST a row click.

Comment: So you can most certainly add a row click event to the grid view. No button is required, just a simple click on any row will trigger the selected index changed event. However, a listview control is much easer to use if you just want a row click. And list view does not required to place standard asp..net controls inside of a template field. Thus I often prefer listview over gridview. But a on-click row event CAN be added to grivdview as the above code show how to do this.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have tried your solution and it has worked for me. Thanks a lot.